# Is running low-voltage DC wire (for LED) between outdoor PVC trim (post wrap) and the wooden post permitted by the national electrical code?

Tags: wiring, led, outdoor, nec

The proposed specific application involves running 16AWG wire (lamp cord) for a 12VDC LED light fixture that will draw a maximum of 2.25 amps, beneath PVC trim in a routed channel with cross-section area of 1/4" (1/2" x 1/2") - thickness of PVC is 1 inch/1/2" along routed channel.  Fixture is rated for outdoor use.  Is this permissible under NEC?  Are there other considerations besides the space in the cavity vs. amperage and wire gauge?  Thank you.

Comment: Usually NEC does not care when the voltage drops below ~50 volts so you can do what you want.  NEC will only care about the circuit going to the transformer, not after.  You don't mention the cable except to say lamp cord.  My understanding of lamp cord is it is not for outside conditions and might not last.  Is the transformer inside the house or at the light fixture?  If at the fixture then your plan needs changing to go by code, at least 14 gauge wire made for wet conditions.

Comment: What ratings does this "lamp cord" carry?

Comment: @crip659 Thank you for the info - to your questions: the cord's rating is not known by me, but it is a lamp and cord designed for outdoor use (landscape lighting), and the transformer is outdoors but in a NEMA 3 enclosure sheltered completely by a roof, only exposure is cold in the winter.

Comment: And, @ThreePhaseEel, thank you for inquiring with your follow-up, see above re: lamp cord.

Comment: AFAIK the only restriction here would be requiring class 2 cable—I think this might be considered "in-wall" but by no means am I a code expert.

Comment: yeah, that's fine, and overkill for the current.